# How can I solve this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving old homework exercises and I don't have the solution to this one:
$$
\int_{\{|z| = 4\}} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2 + 1}dz
$$
When $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

My thoughts:

$e^{zt} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^nt^n}{n!}$, and the sum is absolutely convergent everywhere, so we can write:

$$
\int_{\{|z| = 4\}} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2 + 1}dz = \int_{\{|z| = 4\}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^nt^n}{n!(z^2 + 1)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\int_{\{|z| = 4\}}\frac{z^n}{(z^2 + 1)}
$$

Now, I've seen this trick in another exercise and I know most of the sum should be 0 and I should be left with some terms that are easy to compute, but I am not sure about the formal explanation.

Can you help me complete my proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int_{|z|=4} \frac{e^{tz}}{z^{2}+1}\ dz = \int_{|z|=4} \frac{e^{tz}}{(z-i)(z+i)}\ dz$$

$$ = 2 \pi i \left( \text{Res} \left[\frac{e^{tz}}{(z-i)(z+i)},i \right]  +\text{Res} \left[\frac{e^{tz}}{(z-i)(z+i)},-i \right]\right)$$

$$ = 2 \pi i \left( \lim_{z \to i} \frac{e^{tz}}{z+i} + \lim_{z \to -i} \frac{e^{tz}}{z-i} \right)$$

$$ =2 \pi i \left( \frac{e^{it}}{2i}+ \frac{e^{-it}}{-2i}\right)$$

$$=\pi \left(e^{it} - e^{-it} \right) = 2 \pi i \sin(t)$$

Comment: Is there a way to solve it without using the residue? I am not sure we learned it when this exercise was handed out.

Comment: In that series, it's going to turn out that the even terms are zero. And you should get $ 2 \pi i $ times the Maclaurin series of $\sin t$. But I would still use the residue theorem to show that. What was the other problem?

Comment: @Hila With a partial fraction decomposition, $$\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{z-i} - \frac{1}{z+i}\right),$$ you can avoid an explicit appeal to the residue theorem, and appeal twice to the Cauchy integral formula instead. Under the hood, however, the integral formula is just a special case of the residue theorem.